# How to read particular excel column values based on particular text and putting it in array in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to search Action in 3rd row and then i need copy all active cell values  in that(Action) column and putting it in array.
I'm beginner please help me.

```
aaaa    Action  bbb
1        4
         6
         7

objCarpetSheet.Range("B2:G2").Value = objInputfileSheet.Range("B16:F16").Value
```

I tried like this but it is reading values from B16 to F16 in CarpetSheet and past in B2 to G2  InputfileSheet.
Actually i want to read used range column value based on particular text and past in another excel.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @FunThomas how to copy 4,6,7 under Action text and putting this in array